# How to include one repository project jar into another repository project

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

How to include Jar from one project in a Git Repository to another project in a different Repository using jenkins

I have a project A in Repository X and i want to build the jar of project A and include it into project B of Repository Y.

Can someone help me how i can do it using jenkins build.

Comment: There are several ways to do this depending on what you need to do otherwise.    The easiest is perhaps to ensure that the two projects share local Maven repository and then tell Jenkins that A and B are linked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** After build the Project A, archive those jar in either file share or artifactory tools (like JFrog, nexus...etc.).

**Step 2:** Create a new config/setting.xml file and update dependency resolution path with fileshare or artifactory tool.

**Navigation:** Manage Jenkins --> Managed files --> Add a new conig --> configure with dependency path.

**Step 3:** While building Project B, use the configured settings.xml file. So that Project B will resolve the Project A jar.

Following Jenkins plugin will help you to build the solution with configured setting.xml file.

[Config File Provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin)